# Razor page and date picker event not firing

Tags: asp.net, datetime, events, razor

I have a Razor page with a date picker, this is bound to a DateTime value in code behind. If the DateTime value is changed it is displayed correctly on the picker. I have attempted to add an "addEventListener" in order to capture the user changing the date picker.

```
<span>
    <label>Expires:</label>
    <input type="date" asp-for="ExpiresDate" id="ExpiresDateTimeControl" style="width: 200px;" />
</span>
```

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        document.getElementById("ExpiresDateTimeControl").addEventListener("change", function () {

            ExpiresDateTimeControlChanged();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Code behind:

```
        public void ExpiresDateTimeControlChanged()
        {
            StoreGlobals();
        }
```

No matter what I try like various event types the event handler is never hit. Any suggestions as to why this is not triggering?